# Handling change in dynamically created textarea element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and open to totally new suggestions concerning my code. I know I might not be following some best practices and I would be happy to be enlightened.
The problem I am facing is that every time a change is made to my textarea, the whole page is rerendered, leading to a loss in focus. So basically, I can only input 1 character at a time, then I have to reclick the textarea again.
I understand that this is caused by the fact that `announcementElements` is dependent on `announcements`. So when `announcements` change, `announcementElements` is rerendered.

My Code

```
import React from 'react';
import { FaThumbtack } from 'react-icons/fa6';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import { dateTime } from '../AppManager';

export default function Announcement({ announcements, setAnnouncements }) {
  
  function handleChange(event){
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setAnnouncements(oldAnnouncements => {
      return oldAnnouncements.map(old => {
        return old.id === name ? {...old, info: value, time: dateTime} : old;
      })
    })
  }

  const announcementsElement = announcements.map(announcement => {
    return <div key={nanoid()}>
      <textarea readOnly={false} className="announce" id={announcement.id} name={announcement.id} value={announcement.info} onChange={handleChange} />
      <label htmlFor={announcement.id} style={{justifyContent: announcement.pinned ? "space-between" : "flex-end"}}>
        {announcement.pinned && <FaThumbtack className='announcepinned' />}
        <span className='announcetime'>{announcement.time}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    function resize(){
      const announceText = document.getElementsByClassName("announce");
      for (let p = 0; p < announceText.length; p++) {
        const ann = announceText[p];
        const height = ann.scrollHeight > 120 ? 120 : ann.scrollHeight;
        ann.style.height = height + "px";
      }
    }
    document.querySelector(".announcement-wrapper").addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", resize);
    return () => {
      document.querySelector(".announcement-wrapper").removeEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", resize);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <section>
        <div className="announcement" id="announcement">
            <h2>Announcements</h2>
            <div className="announcement-wrapper"> 
              {announcementsElement}
            </div>
            <div id="add1">
                <button id="add" className="download update">Add</button>        
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Announcement Array

```
[
    {
        "id": "etmlkmlekrmpe",
        "info":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "pinned": false,
        "time":"20/12/23 10:16:23"
    },
    {
        "id": "okoikowekl",
        "info":"Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur.",
        "pinned": false,
        "time":"21/12/23 10:16:23"
    },
    {
        "id": "oolkmuhyuf",
        "info":"Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur",
        "pinned": true,
        "time":"13/12/23 10:16:23"
    },
    {
        "id": "kmkmlmklmkl",
        "info":"Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet",
        "pinned": false,
        "time":"25/12/23 10:16:23"
    }
]
```

I have tried using `useRef()`, but it doesn't solve the problem

```
const announceRef = React.useRef([]);
  announceRef.current = announcements;

const announcementsElement = announceRef.current.map(announcement => {
    return <div key={nanoid()}>
      <textarea readOnly={false} className="announce" id={announcement.id} name={announcement.id} value={announcement.info} onChange={handleChange} />
      <label htmlFor={announcement.id} style={{justifyContent: announcement.pinned ? "space-between" : "flex-end"}}>
        {announcement.pinned && <FaThumbtack className='announcepinned' />}
        <span className='announcetime'>{announcement.time}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  });
```

Comment: You could try using `useMemo`, the documentation for which can be found [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a fix to my problem, so I took an entirely new approach
Instead of using the `onChange` listener, I decided to work with the `onBlur` listener.
`onBlur` is triggered when an element previously focused on isn't any more.
That way, the user can type everything without being interrupted by the change. A submit button is also needed to complete the update, so the `onBlur` event would occur.
Since I can't have a `textarea` or `input` element in React without an `onChange` listener (I think so), I had to change from using `textarea` to a `div` with a `contentEnditable` property.

Here is my updated code

```
import React from 'react';
import { FaThumbtack } from 'react-icons/fa6';
import { dateTime } from '../AppManager';

export default function Announcement({ announcements, setAnnouncements }) {
  function resize(){
    const announceText = document.getElementsByClassName("announce");
    for (let p = 0; p < announceText.length; p++) {
      const ann = announceText[p];
      const height = ann.scrollHeight > 120 ? 120 : ann.scrollHeight;
      ann.style.height = height + "px";
    }
  }

  function AnnouncementBox({ id, info, pinned, time, admin = true, handleChange, resize }){
    return <div>
      <div contentEditable={admin} className="announce" id={id} onBlur={handleChange} onKeyUp={resize}>
        {info}
      </div>
      <label htmlFor={id} style={{justifyContent: pinned ? "space-between" : "flex-end"}}>
        {pinned && <FaThumbtack className='announcepinned' />}
        <span className='announcetime'>{time}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  }

  function handleChange(event){
    const { id, innerText } = event.target;
    setAnnouncements(oldAnnouncements => {
      return oldAnnouncements.map(old => {
        return old.id === id ? {...old, info: innerText, time: dateTime} : old;
      })
    });
  }

  const announcementsElement = announcements.map(announcement => {
    return <AnnouncementBox key={announcement.id} id={announcement.id} info={announcement.info} pinned={announcement.pinned} time={announcement.time} handleChange={handleChange} admin={true} resize={resize} />
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector(".announcement-wrapper").addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", resize);
    return () => {
      document.querySelector(".announcement-wrapper").removeEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", resize);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <section>
        <div className="announcement" id="announcement">
            <h2>Announcements</h2>
            <div className="announcement-wrapper"> 
              {announcementsElement}
            </div>
            <div id="add1">
                <button id="add" className="download update">Add</button>        
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
  )
}
```

So, I would be using this for now, but will keep track of this question if someone has a better solution.

I have another question though, is it actually possible to have an `input` or `textarea` without an `onChange` listener?
I would prefer to continue using the `textarea` if possible

Answer (score 0):

React is a very simple system:

- your app is a 'tree of components'
- a 'component' is simply a JavaScript function
- each component can have its own data stored in "state" (via `useState()`)
- a component gets 'rendered' (i.e. the function is run) under only 2 cases:

  1. its parent is rendered, so that parent renders all its children
  2. state in the component is modified via the "set state function"

In your case you are sending the "set state function" from the parent down to `Announcement`, and then having the text area update the PARENT'S STATE everytime the text area has a new value (every single key press).

So it is the PARENT that is re-rendering, which then re-renders `Announcement`.

This is likely NOT what you want.

Where to store "state" in the tree of components is part of the "art" of React.  Understanding the simple rules listed above will help you determine where to store state, and when to pass new values upwards towards your parent (if ever)

I suspect what you really want to do is to store the value of the textarea as state in Announcement, and then have some other trigger that sends that value to the parent (if needed).  Maybe you offer a SAVE button or have some type of debouncing timer that sets the value on the parent after some time delay?

....or...do you even need to set STATE on the parent at all?  Could you pass the value as a standard variable rather than a "set state function"?

---

Addtionally, recognize that when you do:

```
announcements.map((announcement) => {
      [[SOME_JSX_STUFF_HERE]]
});
```

the `[[SOME_JSX_STUFF_HERE]]` is actually a separate React component. If you want to track state for each iteration of that .map(), then consider putting state (i.e. use useState()) inside `[[SOME_JSX_STUFF_HERE]]`.

And...to be a better/cleaner codebase, move the definition of `[[SOME_JSX_STUFF_HERE]]` to its own file (e.g. `SomeJsxStuffHere.jsx`) so that it is clear that this is a component, and that it be maintained as such.

Comment: Thank you for this.   I actually understand the concept better now.   I am sending the "set state function" from the parent down to `Announcement` because the parent is also making use of the state.   Do you think my solution is okay?

Comment: The fact that you are updating state of the parent with every single key click is likely the cause of your UX issues.  I would myself keep the "value" of the textarea in a state variable in the component with the textarea, and send the value up to the parent with the user "finishes" inputting to the textarea -- either via an event like `onBlur()` or some other user-initiated action like a "save" button.